# How to hg bundle only changes in a branch?

Tags: mercurial

I have tried this:

```
$ hg bundle -b my-branch ../my-branch-bundle.hg
searching for changes
no changes found
```

Then this:

```
$ hg bundle --all --branch my-branch ../my-branch-bundle.hg
7191 changesets found
```

... but my branch has only 3 commits? Then also this:

```
$ hg bundle --base null --branch my-branch ../my-branch-bundle.hg
7191 changesets found
```

How to `hg bundle` **only** the changes for a given branch?!

Answer (score 2):

`hg bundle` bundles each specified revision (-r) and assumes the destination repository has all the revisions (and their ancestors) specified by the `--base` option.

So one way to get only a small branch of 3 changesets is to specify with `--base` the first changeset branched from, and specify of the first changeset of the branch and its descendants.

For example, given:

```
o  changeset:   5:f429f686e698
|  branch:      test
|
o  changeset:   4:e02923c7302b
|  branch:      test
|
o  changeset:   3:076f442d4d3b
|  branch:      test
|
| @  changeset:   2:dab4279642cb
|/
o  changeset:   1:233d09b80d63
|
o  changeset:   0:6818527e85ac
```

Use:

```
hg bundle --base 1 --rev heads(descendants(3))
```